# How to build columns with months from datetime series?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

So I have this data with ID, date, and if they did activities on that day

```
ID             DATE              DONE  
1           2009-1-3             Yes
1           2009-1-15            Yes
2           2009-9-3             Yes
3           2009-10-7            No
1           2009-12-1            Yes
3           2009-10-8            Yes
2           2009-10-21           Yes
```

So I want to groupby and create columns with months and 1 if they did the activity in that month 0 o.w

```
ID 2009-1 2009-2 ... 2009-9 2009-10 2009-11 2009-12
1     1     0    ...   0         0       0     1
2     0     0    ...   1         1       0     0
3     0     0    ...   0         0       0     0
```

Thank you

Comment: Sry overlook the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Series` `groupby`+ `all` then with `unstack`

```
s=df['DONE'].eq('Yes').\
      groupby([df['ID'],df.DATE.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')]).\
          all().astype(int).unstack(fill_value=0)
s
Out[1026]: 
DATE  2009-01  2009-09  2009-10  2009-12
ID                                      
1           1        0        0        1
2           0        1        1        0
3           0        0        0        0
```

Comment: Thanks so much. On unrelated note, what resources are the best for mastering pandas? I know the basics of it, but when it comes to complex stuff, I am having hard time.

Comment: @jarge just my personal experience , you can check the book Pandas cook book https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/cookbook.html or the book https://books.google.com/books/about/Pandas_Cookbook.html?id=yRhKDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way

#### `Setup`

```
df.DATE = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE)
df.DONE = df.DONE.map({'Yes':1, 'No':0})
```

---

#### `Solution`

Then create an auxiliary int column in the style `200901`

```
df['DATE2']=df.DATE.dt.year.astype(str).add(df.DATE.dt.month.astype(str).str.zfill(2)).astype(int)
```

and `pivot_table`+`reindex`

```
df.pivot_table(columns='DATE2', index='ID', values='DONE').reindex(np.arange(200901, 200913), axis='columns').fillna(0)


DATE2   200901  200902  200903  200904  200905  200906  200907  200908  200909  200910  200911  200912
ID                                              
1       1.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     1.0
2       0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     1.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
3       0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.5     0.0     0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late but I think that this solution is quite nice, too:

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
(df.pivot(columns='DATE', values='DONE') == 'Yes') + 0
```